# Heroku github deploy method error "Internal server error"

Tags: javascript, github, heroku, oauth

When I try to add GitHub as my deployment method, it just pops up ands says one of these two things. [Error1(image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqnQ7.png)

[Error 2(image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W83LB.png)

But the really odd part is that when I look on GitHub it shows Heroku as a OAuth application that is added but says it was never used. And then, in logs it says things like this:

[Error logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CbMI.png)

Does anyone know what's going on? I'm using Heroku to host a discord bot and ever since I logged out of GitHub on Heroku because it was acting up I cant get back in.

Answer (score 1):

deploy from github is currently unavailable due to some hacker attack

reference: https://status.heroku.com/incidents/2413

> We are dedicated to ensuring the security of our customers, and as
> such, continue to pursue all potential leads as part of our
> investigation. As part of that commitment, we want to let you know
> about two additional findings that may impact a small number of our
> customers.
>
> As reported on status.heroku.com, on April 7, 2022, a threat actor
> obtained access to a Heroku database and downloaded stored customer
> GitHub integration OAuth tokens. On that same day, the threat actor
> downloaded data from another database that stores pipeline-level
> config vars for Review Apps and Heroku CI. Additionally, another small
> subset of Heroku users had their Heroku tokens exposed in a config var
> for a pipeline. This was identified on May 16, 2022, after further
> forensic investigation. We have no evidence of any unauthorized access
> to Heroku systems since April 14, 2022.
>
> Any users affected by these issues were notified directly and provided
> with additional guidance. If you did not receive an email directly
> from us, we have no evidence that you were impacted by either of these
> recently identified issues. If you received an email from Salesforce
> (techcomms@mail.salesforce.com) and have identified suspicious
> activity, please contact security@salesforce.com.
>
> For an update on our current progress with regards to the GitHub
> integration, please see this blog post.

so you can deploy manually through heroku CLI

Comment: Thank you, I was wondering if that was the case because I had seen the thing about Heroku being under attack thanks!

Answer (score 1):

as @MarcoWriteCode has mentioned the basis of the error that you are facing.
I would suggest that you go through the Heroku CLI documentation and continue your deployment from here. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs

Answer (score -1):

Use heroku CLI for a bit, then switch back to github deploys